# Converting char* to unsigned char*

Tags: c, char, sha1, unsigned, strcpy

How do I copy a char* to a unsigned char* correctly in C. Following is my code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char *digest;

    digest = malloc(20 * sizeof(unsigned char));
    strncpy(digest, argv[2], 20);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to correctly copy char* array to unsigned char* array. I get the following warning using the above code

```
warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of âstrncpyâ differ in signedness
```

*EDIT*: Adding more information, My requirement is that the caller provide a SHA digest to the main function as a string on command line and the main function internally save it in the digest. SHA digest can be best represented using a unsigned char.

Now the catch is that I can't change the signature of the main function (** char) because the main function parses other arguments which it requires as char* and not unsigned char*.

Comment: A hash digest is typically expressed as an ASCII representation of the hex value of the digest (e.g. "`b6379dab2c...`").  A `char` is absolutely fine for this!

Comment: @oli So basically the cast should also work fine without any problems strncpy((char*)digest, argv[2], 20); since we are dealing with ASCII?

Comment: @Rajiv: there are two different ways to represent an SHA-1 digest, which is 160 bits. One of those ways is to use 20 8-bit bytes, and `unsigned char` is the best type for this. The other way is to use an ASCII representation in which each character is a hexadecimal digit, representing 4 bits, and hence 40 of them are required. Clearly `strncpy` isn't going to convert between them.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah I am using the unsigned char version with 20 8bits. If strncpy cannot would memcpy or any other function would do the trick?

Comment: @Rajiv: how do you think the user is going to type those 8-bit values at the terminal? What if one of them is 0?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To avoid the compiler warning, you simply need:

```
strncpy((char *)digest, argv[2], 20);
```

But avoiding the compiler warning is often **not** a good idea; it's telling you that there is a fundamental incompatibility.  In this case, the incompatibility is that `char` has a range of -128 to +127 (typically), whereas `unsigned char` is 0 to +255.

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem, how do I solve the incompatibility in a better way?

Comment: If you could tell us why you need in as an unsigned char, that might help us answer? To take a guess at a better solution you maybe should be using a structure or union instead of a blob of unsigned char memory.

Comment: In the case of `char *` vs `unsigned char *`, the warning (which, per the standard, the compiler is supposed to treat as an error!) is rarely indicative of any bug except a bug in the standard. Almost all of the standard functions take `char *` but deal with data which is really treated as an array of `unsigned char`. See `strcmp`.

Comment: @R..: What do you mean "treated as an array of `unsigned char`"?

Comment: I gave `strcmp` as an example. It's required to make its comparison based on the difference between the first non-matching bytes *interpreted as `unsigned char`*.

Comment: There are also issues with the fact that, on a non-twos-complement implementation where `char` is signed, the value 0 could have two representations, while only the all-bits-0 byte is the null terminator. This means any function that deals with null terminated strings on such an implementation must be dealing with them as `unsigned char []` in order to tell the difference. Admittedly, any non-twos-complement implementation where plain `char` is signed would be rather stupid to begin with though...

Answer (score 6):

You can't **correctly** copy it since there is difference in types, compiler warns you just about that.

If you need to copy raw bits of `argv[2]` array you should use `memcpy` function.

Comment: With `memcpy`, you first need to check the length of `argv[2]` to avoid accessing elements outside the array.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the signedness away in the `strncpy()` call

```
strncpy((char*)digest, argv[2], 20);
```

or introduce another variable

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char *digest;
    void *tmp;                   /* (void*) is compatible with both (char*) and (unsigned char*) */

    digest = malloc(20 * sizeof *digest);
    if (digest) {
        tmp = digest;
        if (argc > 2) strncpy(tmp, argv[2], 20);
        free(digest);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "No memory.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Also note that `malloc(20 * sizeof(unsigned char*))` is probably not what you want. I think you want `malloc(20 * sizeof(unsigned char))`, or, as by definition `sizeof (unsigned char)` is `1`, `malloc(20)`.
If you really want to use the size of each element in the call, use the object itself, like in my code above.

Comment: IMO, introducing a dummy variable here just obfuscates the code, with no corresponding benefit.

Comment: The OP apparently wants a "better way than a cast". The obfuscated `(void*)` variable accomplishes a different way: I'll leave the decision if it's better to the OP (like you, @Oli, I think it isn't).

Answer (score 1):

You can use memcpy as:

```
memcpy(digest, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
```

as the underlying type of objects pointed to by src and dest pointers are irrelevant for this function.

Comment: You have no guarantee accessing `argv[2][19]` is allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure the `'\0'` is needed in `digest`. Anyway, now you need to check that `strlen(argv[2])` is small enough for the size allocated for `digest` :)

Comment: @pmg hmm...then OP have to synchronize the allocation size for digest with the (strlen (argv[2]) + 1) * sizeof (unsigned char)

Comment: On some strange machines, sizeof(char) may not be 1. eg TMS320C40. Showing my age here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one way to convert `char *` to `unsigned char *`. They point to data, and you must know the format of the data.

There are at least 3 different formats for a SHA-1 hash:

- the raw binary digest as an array of exactly 20 octets
- the digest as a hexadecimal string, like `"e5e9fa1ba31ecd1ae84f75caaa474f3a663f05f4"`
- the digest as a Base64 string, like `"5en6G6MezRroT3XKqkdPOmY/BfQ="`

Your `malloc(20 * sizeof(unsigned char))` has the exact size of a binary digest, but is too small to fit a hexadecimal string or a Base64 string. I guess that the `unsigned char *` points to a binary digest.

But the `char *` came from the command-line arguments of `main()`, so the `char *` probably points to a string. Command-line arguments are always C strings; they end with the NUL terminator `'\0'` and never contain `'\0'` in the string. Raw binary digests might contain `'\0'`, so they don't work as command-line arguments.

The code to convert a SHA-1 digest from hexadecimal string to raw binary might look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char *
sha1_from_hex(char *hex)
{
    int i, m, n, octet;
    unsigned char *digest;

    digest = malloc(20);
    if (!digest)
        return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        sscanf(hex, " %n%2x%n", &m, &octet, &n);
        if (m != 0 || n != 2)
            goto fail;
        digest[i] = octet;
        hex += 2;
    }
    if (*hex)
        goto fail;
    return digest;

fail:
    free(digest);
    return NULL;
}
```

Don't use `strncpy(dst, src, 20)` to copy raw binary digests. The [strncpy(3)](http://man.openbsd.org/man3/strncpy.3) function stops copying if it finds a `'\0'`; so if your digest contains `'\0'`, you lose part of the digest.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `(char*)` in front of it
or `(unsigned char*)`

Answer (score 0):

Warning is simply what it says , you are passing an unsigned char *  digest to strncpy function which is in different signedness from what it expects.